# Запоминание текущего значения диапазона ползунком JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-form

Есть функция выборки диапазона годов. Как сделать, чтобы выбранные значения запоминались, чтобы, допустим, если в постраничной навигации перейти на вторую страницу, значения были те же, что ввел пользователь, а не сбрасывались по умолчанию?

```
$(function() {
$( "#slider-range" ).slider({
range: true,
min: 1927,
max: 2015,
values: [ 1987, 2010 ],
slide: function( event, ui ) {
$( "#start-film" ).val( ui.values[0] );
$( "#end-film" ).val( ui.values[1] );
}
});
$( "#start-film" ).val($( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) );
$( "#end-film" ).val($( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
});
```

Ну вот, допустим, что в обычном HtmlPhp можно было бы сделать так:

```
от <input class="searchyear" type="text" name="start-film" id="start-film" value="<?=$startgod?>"/>
до <input class="searchyear" type="text" name="end-film" id="end-film" value="<?=$endgod?>"/>
```

учитывая, что

```
$startgod = (int)$_GET['start-film'];
$endgod = (int)$_GET['end-film'];
```

Comment: @KoRNeT46RuS, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Записывай каждое значение в куки.

Например, `document.cookie="val1=123";`.

И тогда у тебя вместо

```
<input class="searchyear" type="text" name="start-film" id="start-film" value="<?=$startgod?>"/>
```

будет

```
<input class="searchyear" type="text" name="start-film" id="start-film" value="<?=$_COOKIE[val1]?>"/>
```

**Обновление**

Перед строкой

```
$( "#start-film" ).val($( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) );
```

добавьте:

```
document.cookie="start_film="+$( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 );
document.cookie="end_film="+$( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 );
```

Comment: А можете показать, как брать значения с инпута и занести в куки. Я с JS не дружу. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Перед строкой

    $( "#start-film" ).val($( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) ); 

добавьте:

    document.cookie="start_film="+$( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 );
    document.cookie="end_film="+$( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 );

Comment: Пробовал добавить и вызвать. Все равно скидывает на умолчание...

Answer (score 0):

Работает код. Только выводить в `value` нужно `$_COOKIE['val1']`

Кавычки нужны при указании ключа.